# Aligning textbox and labels in html using css

Tags: html, css

When I only have 1 label and 1 text box per line. I align them using float:left and float:right then squeeze them by using field set's width.

But what I need to do now is 3 labels and 3 text boxes per line. Any idea how to align them?

Edit: Ignore the name, I just copy pasted so they have same name LOL

```
<fieldset style='width:auto;margin:auto;' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
    <legend>Add Hardware Availability</legend>
       <p>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Hardware Type: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Repair Priority: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpLName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>RTP Target: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
       </p>

       <p>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Hardware Name: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Date Needed: </label><input type='date' required name='txtEmpLName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Shortages: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
       </p>

       <p>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Facility: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
          <label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Reason: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd' size='60'>
       </p>
</fieldset>
```

[This is what I had in mind to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcd5G.jpg)

[image]

[Current look without css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkxk2.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use one experienced framework that has this in the box, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)... But if you want to do it yourself, one possible approach is the following:

```css
fieldset {
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
.row div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  text-align:right;
}
input {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style='width:auto;margin:auto;' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>
  <legend>Add Hardware Availability</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Hardware Type: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Repair Priority: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpLName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>RTP Target: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Hardware Name: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Date Needed: </label><input type='date' required name='txtEmpLName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Shortages: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Facility: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpNum' class='hardwareavailabilityadd'></div>
    <div><label class='hardwareavailabilityadd'>Reason: </label><input type='text' required name='txtEmpFName' class='hardwareavailabilityadd' size='60'></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks this will do. I'm still a beginner in css so I don't know any framework. 

But first I will study the css code you've given me so I can know how did it happen.

I like how the label sticks to the textboxes.

Comment: Just a bit more. I'm planning to make the reason text box span to the end. But now if I extend it, it goes down.

Comment: To do it you need to put a custom class in the reason's container `div` and set some CSS to make it use `66%` of the `width` instead of `33%`. You will need to change the label's width too, because just increasing the size of the div will dishevel this label from the others, as it's size rely on percentages.